# React: Send parameter to Parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state, action

I have two components (parent and child).
I want to send a parameter to parent component, it works but with a slight delay.

Parent component:

```js
const [isMove, setMove] = useState(true);

   return (
      <ResponsiveGridLayout
        cols={cols}
        layouts={layouts}
        className='layout'
        isResizable={false}
        isDraggable={isMove}
        compactType='horizontal'
        rowHeight={200}
        measureBeforeMount
      >
        {picture.map((widget, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index.toString()} className='card'>
              // "isMove" should forbid element from moving
              <Header widget={widget} isMove={setMove} />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </ResponsiveGridLayout>
   );
```

Child:

```js
const Pen = ({isMove}) => {

   function onClickByPen(event){
      isMove(false);
   };

   return(
     <div>
       <button type='button' onMouseDown={onClickByPen}>
        Tets
       </button>
     <div>
   )
};
```

How do I send a parameter instantly?
When I press the button and move the mouse, the function forbiding does not have time to work.

Comment: Could you please add the relevant JSX code also? For parent and child components

Comment: @ Harmandeep Singh Kalsi edited question

Comment: Could you please help me understand , where are you using <Pen /> that is child component in the parent component , or better option will be if you could provide the sandbox of the code .